# Analytic continuation of $I(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int^\infty_0 f(x)x^{s-1}\, dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, analytic-continuation, schwartz-space

This is Exercise 17 of Chapter 6 from Stein and Shakarchi Complex analysis

> Let $f$ be an infinitely differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$
> that has compact support, or more generally, let $f$ belongs to the
> Schwartz space. Consider $$I(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int^\infty_0
>  f(x)x^{s-1}\, dx$$ (a) Observe that $I(s)$ is holomorphic for
> $Re(s)>0$. Prove that $I$ has an analytic continuation as an entire
> function in the complex plane.
>
> (b) Prove that $I(0)=0$, and more generally $$I(-n)=(-1)^nf^{(n+1)}(0)$$ for all $n\geq 0$.

There is also a hint which tells us to show the formula $$I(s)=\frac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(s+k)}\int^\infty_0 f^{(k)}(x)x^{s+k-1}\, dx$$
I have no difficulty in showing this and proving part (a), where I used this formula to define $I(s)$ for $Re(s)>-k$.

However, I couldn't prove the second part, not even $I(0)=0$. Let's say $s=0$, then we may choose $k=1$. By $\Gamma(1)=1$ and the fact that $f$ belongs to the Schwartz space (which means $f$ and all its derivatives decay faster than any polynomials), we could obtain $I(0)=f(0)$, which is non-zero in general.

I must have made some mistakes here, because my calculation above doesn't hold for $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, which I believe satisfy the given conditions.

EDIT: This is likely a typo from the book. $I(0)=f(0)$ and $I(-n)=(-1)^nf^{(n)}(0)$ are the correct answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}dx=\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k! (s+k)}+\int_0^1 (f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^K f^{(k)}(0)\frac{x^k}{k!})x^{s-1}dx+\int_1^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}dx$$
The RHS gives the meromorphic continuation to $\Re(s) > -K-1$

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to an entire function? Because otherwise I couldn't find their values at 0 and at negative integers. Your continuation has poles at those points.

Comment: Because I didn't multiply with $1/\Gamma(s)$